# Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: req is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express setup. For some reason req is not being recognized in this function:

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
  ;(async (req, res) => { //req and res here are just parameters in function definition
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(`https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22this+is%22`)
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
      console.log('CLAUSESS:', req.body.clauses)
      const clauses = req.body.clauses
      return clauses.map(clause => clause.textContent)
    })
    result.join('\n')
    await browser.close()
    res.send(result)
  })(req,res); //This is where we call the function, so we need to pass the actual values here.
})
```

This is the error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: req is
>   not defined
>       at :2:32

What could be the reason?

Comment: semicolon in line 2; remove it and see if things work

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram I removed the semicolon. Same error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: req is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:32`

Comment: can u console.log(req) before line 2?

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram There's a large: `IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {` So I think it exists there.

Comment: I could be wrong here, so exercise caution: I looked into some of examples of Immediately invoked async function expressions, But none of them are passing arguments; I couldnt find explanation or if it is even an issue; can u research in that direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value from an express route handler doesn't matter, so it can be `async`

```
router.post('/search', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(`https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22this+is%22`)
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
      console.log('CLAUSESS:', req.body.clauses)
      const clauses = req.body.clauses
      return clauses.map(clause => clause.textContent)
    })
    result.join('\n')
    await browser.close()
    res.send(result)
  }
  catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})
```

Comment: Strange. I'm still getting `theerror: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: req is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:32`

Comment: Do you have any middleware running before this route?

Comment: Or possibly something compiling this code to run it?

Comment: I forgot to add the bodyParser.